# Android Studio cannot delete import library module

Tags: android-studio

Cannot delete import library module. It will kept appeared after restart android studio or add new module even after delete it in Project Structure.

1) Module that I want to delete

[image: image1]

2) Delete from Project Structure

[image: image2]

3) Module still appeared after restart android studio or add new module

[image: image3]

After update Android Studio from version 3.0.1 to 3.13. This problem happen to me and I have no problem with Android Studio 3.0.1. Can someone guide me about this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check in your `settings.gradle` file there should be a line that starts with: `include ':app'`

You should remove the import to the libraries on this line, in your case something like:

`':pipwavesdklibrary-debug', :pipwavesdklibrary-release'`

Also remove the library from your project structure if no longer needed.

Comment: thank you, usually I delete from project structure and it will work fine.But this method is work like charm, all unused module completely removed.